# vBulletin 5.x.x 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: vbulletin, laragon

I am trying to install vBulletin5 on my pc. I am uisng Laragon. I got 500 Internal Server Error. When I remove .htaccess everything works fine till installation done. 

Here is .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #In some cases where you have other mod_rewrite rules, you may need to comment out the following line
    #and change it to match your folder name. This resets the other mod_rewrite rules for just this directory
    #If your site was www.example.com/forum, the setting would be /forum/
    #RewriteBase /

    # Send css calls directly to the correct file VBV-7807
    RewriteRule ^css.php$ core/css.php [NC,L]

    # Redirect old install path to core.
    RewriteRule ^install/ core/install/ [NC,L]

    # Main Redirect
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?routestring=$1 [L,QSA]

    # Because admincp is an actual directory.
    RewriteRule ^(admincp/)$ index.php?routestring=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                          text/javascript \
                          application/x-javascript \
                          application/javascript \
                          application/json \
                          application/rss+xml \
                          application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                          application/x-font-ttf \
                          application/xhtml+xml \
                          application/xml \
                          font/opentype \
                          image/svg+xml \
                          image/x-icon \
                          text/css \
                          text/html \
                          text/plain \
                          text/x-component \
                          text/xml
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A1209600
    ExpiresByType text/javascript A1209600
    ExpiresByType application/javascript A1209600
    ExpiresByType text/css A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2592000
    ExpiresByType image/icon A2592000
    ExpiresByType application/x-ico A2592000
    ExpiresByType application/ico A2592000
    ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg A1209600
    ExpiresByType image/jpg A1209600
    ExpiresByType image/png A1209600
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A1209600
    ExpiresByType font/ttf A2592000
    ExpiresByType font/otf A2592000
    ExpiresByType font/x-woff A2592000
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A2592000
    ExpiresByType font/truetype A2592000
    ExpiresByType font/opentype A2592000
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff A2592000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A2592000
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Connection keep-alive
    <filesmatch "\.(ico|flv|gif|swf|eot|woff|otf|ttf|svg)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
    </filesmatch>
    <filesmatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1209600, public"
    </filesmatch>
    <filesmatch "\.(eot|woff|otf|ttf|svg)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
    </filesmatch>
    # css and js should use private for proxy caching https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching#LeverageProxyCaching
    <filesmatch "\.(css)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, private"
    </filesmatch>
    <filesmatch "\.(js)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1209600, private"
    </filesmatch>
</IfModule>
```

Apache error.log

```
[Sun Jan 31 16:59:14.077148 2016] [core:alert] [pid 6492:tid 916] [client 127.0.0.1:63045] D:/lamp/www/forum/.htaccess: Invalid command 'AddOutputFilterByType', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://forum.dev/core/install/install.php
[Sun Jan 31 17:17:38.028320 2016] [core:alert] [pid 6492:tid 916] [client 127.0.0.1:63417] D:/lamp/www/forum/.htaccess: Invalid command 'AddOutputFilterByType', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Sun Jan 31 17:17:38.191406 2016] [core:alert] [pid 6492:tid 916] [client 127.0.0.1:63418] D:/lamp/www/forum/.htaccess: Invalid command 'AddOutputFilterByType', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://forum.dev/core/install/install.php
```

Could anybody help?

Comment: See Your servers log files, there must be more info about what is wrong with configuration. And show Your .htaccess file.

Comment: And what does error log shows?

Comment: where can I find error logs in Laragon?

Comment: depends where You installed laragon: `C:\laragon\bin\apache\apache-2.4.17\logs`

Answer (score 3):

just remove:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                      text/javascript \
                      application/x-javascript \
                      application/javascript \
                      application/json \
                      application/rss+xml \
                      application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                      application/x-font-ttf \
                      application/xhtml+xml \
                      application/xml \
                      font/opentype \
                      image/svg+xml \
                      image/x-icon \
                      text/css \
                      text/html \
                      text/plain \
                      text/x-component \
                      text/xml
</IfModule>
```

There are incompatibilities with `mod_deflate` and `mod_filter` between Apache versions 2.2 and 2.4

You need three modules for `mod_deflate` to work in apache 2.4

```
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
```

So either remove that block, or load `mod_filter`